# Why does variable === "Work" evaluate to false when the value is set to "work"?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm working with two different lists(arrays) which, in theory, are supposed to store different kind of information. Down below are the two arrays.

```
let items = ["Buy Food", "Cook Food", "Eat Food"]; 
let workItems = [];
```

The code below is responsible for assigning values to each array, based on the value(name of the list to which the item belongs) passed to the function .

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){
let item = req.body.newItem; 
  var a = req.body.list;//this variable stores the list name
  var b = "Work";
 console.log(a, b);// When 'a' is "Work", this prints: "Work" "Work"
//My problem starts here
//When the value stored in 'a' is "Work",  the comparison below never returns true, even though they're >//the same thing.

  if ( a === b){
//never got here!
    workItems.push(item);
    console.log(workItems);//At this stage it shouldn't be an ampty array
   res.redirect ("/work");
  } else{
    items.push(item);
    res.redirect ("/");
    console.log(workItems)
    }
});
```

Terminal: [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRX8i.png)
complete code link https://controlc.com/8931bb24

Comment: Try `console.log(a)` to double-check. To triple- and quadruple-check, try `console.log(a === 'Work')`, `console.log(a === b)`, etc. Try logging everything you can think of; eventually you will figure out what went wrong. Also don’t use `var` anymore — always use `const` unless you *absolutely need* it to be `let`.

Comment: if a and b are both `Work` and are both strings, then there a === b would hold true. Did you try console.log(req.body.list) to see that the value was indeed the string `Work`

Comment: Please execute the following `var a_type = typeof a; var b_type = typeof b; console.log({ a, b, a_type, b_type })` and share its output.

Comment: Output: { a: 'Work ', b: 'work', a_type: 'string', b_type: 'string' } //Now I see where trouble is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your screenshot, it looks like there are two spaces between the `Work  Work` console output. One possible reason is that you actually get  `Work` as variable `a`. If you want to ignore this you can use trim():

`if (a.trim() === b)`

Moreover, if you are interested only in semantic meaning and not the case to can compare to a lower-cased string:

`if (a.trim().toLowerCase() === 'work')`

If that is not working for you, you should check more thoroughly what is the value of `a`, most probably, it's not 'Work' exactly.